# Open a new view using mapPin button Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

I am developing an app in Xcode (objective-c). My app has a TableView with a list of restaurants and when you press one row, another view is opened with the restaurant information. The method I am using is that I am sending the title in the row to the new view and depending on the title I load the information of the restaurant.
I want to do exactly the same using a map pin button. I have a map with pins and I want to press the right detail button an open another view with the restaurant information depending on the mapPin title.

Can someone help me! I was looking for tutorial and other posts but it doesn't work in my case. Thank you very much!

This is my MapViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController {

    MKMapView *mapView;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barButton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender;

@end
```

This is my MapViewController.m:

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "RestMapPin.h"
#import "RestViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController

@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _barButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString (@"Map", nil)]; /*Cambia el titulo del navigation controller*/

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}]; /*Cambia el color de las letras del navigation controller bar del menu principal*/

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:27/255.0f green:101/255.0f blue:163/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; /*Cambia el color del boton de la izquierda*/

    mapView.delegate = self;

    //1
    //80 Grados
    MKCoordinateRegion region_80_grados = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
    region_80_grados.center.latitude = 40.42871179999999;
    region_80_grados.center.longitude =  -3.703639100000032;
    region_80_grados.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    region_80_grados.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    [mapView setRegion:region_80_grados animated:YES];

    RestMapPin *ann_80_grados = [[RestMapPin alloc] init];
    ann_80_grados.title = @"80 Grados";
    ann_80_grados.subtitle = @"Malasaña";
    ann_80_grados.coordinate = region_80_grados.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann_80_grados];

    //90 Grados
    MKCoordinateRegion region_90_grados = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
    region_90_grados.center.latitude = 40.4164161;
    region_90_grados.center.longitude =  -3.6699459999999817;
    region_90_grados.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    region_90_grados.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    [mapView setRegion:region_90_grados animated:YES];

    RestMapPin *ann_90_grados = [[RestMapPin alloc] init];
    ann_90_grados.title = @"90 Grados";
    ann_90_grados.subtitle = @"Retiro";
    ann_90_grados.coordinate = region_90_grados.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann_90_grados];

    /*B&B Babel*/
    MKCoordinateRegion region_babel = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
    region_babel.center.latitude = 40.4214535;
    region_babel.center.longitude =  -3.6974301;
    region_babel.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    region_babel.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    [mapView setRegion:region_babel animated:YES];

    RestMapPin *ann_babel = [[RestMapPin alloc] init];
    ann_babel.title = @"B&B Babel";
    ann_babel.subtitle = @"Barrio de Chueca";
    ann_babel.coordinate = region_babel.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann_babel];

    /*Babelia*/
    MKCoordinateRegion region_Babelia = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
    region_Babelia.center.latitude = 40.4234778;
    region_Babelia.center.longitude =  -3.686283000000003;
    region_Babelia.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    region_Babelia.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    [mapView setRegion:region_Babelia animated:YES];

    RestMapPin *ann_Babelia = [[RestMapPin alloc] init];
    ann_Babelia.title = @"Babelia";
    ann_Babelia.subtitle = @"Barrio de Salamanca";
    ann_Babelia.coordinate = region_Babelia.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann_Babelia];

    /*Bacira*/
    MKCoordinateRegion region_Bacira = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
    region_Bacira.center.latitude = 40.43375390000001;
    region_Bacira.center.longitude =  -3.699036299999989;
    region_Bacira.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    region_Bacira.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    [mapView setRegion:region_Bacira animated:YES];

    RestMapPin *ann_Bacira = [[RestMapPin alloc] init];
    ann_Bacira.title = @"Bacira";
    ann_Bacira.subtitle = @"Chamberí";
    ann_Bacira.coordinate = region_Bacira.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann_Bacira];

    /*Bar Galleta*/
    MKCoordinateRegion region_bar_galleta = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
    region_bar_galleta.center.latitude = 40.4227336;
    region_bar_galleta.center.longitude =  -3.7036699999999882;
    region_bar_galleta.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    region_bar_galleta.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    [mapView setRegion:region_bar_galleta animated:YES];

    RestMapPin *ann_bar_galleta = [[RestMapPin alloc] init];
    ann_bar_galleta.title = @"Bar Galleta";
    ann_bar_galleta.subtitle = @"Malasaña";
    ann_bar_galleta.coordinate = region_bar_galleta.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann_bar_galleta];

    /*Bar Tomate*/
    MKCoordinateRegion region_bar_tomate = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
    region_bar_tomate.center.latitude = 40.428041;
    region_bar_tomate.center.longitude =  -3.69047;
    region_bar_tomate.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    region_bar_tomate.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;
    [mapView setRegion:region_bar_tomate animated:YES];

    RestMapPin *ann_bar_tomate = [[RestMapPin alloc] init];
    ann_bar_tomate.title = @"Bar Tomate";
    ann_bar_tomate.subtitle = @"Chamberí";
    ann_bar_tomate.coordinate = region_bar_tomate.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann_bar_tomate];




    /*Indicador de posicion del mapa (para centrarlo)*/
    MKCoordinateRegion region_posicion = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
    region_posicion.center.latitude = 40.44934744420573;
    region_posicion.center.longitude =  -3.695504665374756;
    region_posicion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.08f;
    region_posicion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.08f;
    [mapView setRegion:region_posicion animated:YES];
    /*************************************************/


}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil )
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                       initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];


        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin2@2x.png"];
    }
    else {
        //[mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }


    UIButton *pinButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Bacira"]) {

    }
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = pinButton;


    return pinView;
}

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {

    switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        case 2:
            mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This is my RestMapPin.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface RestMapPin : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

And this is my RestMapPin.m:

```
#import "RestMapPin.h"

@implementation RestMapPin

@synthesize  coordinate, title, subtitle;

@end
```

Finally this is the view where the information of the restaurants will appear:  RestViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Restaurant.h"

@interface RestViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DescriptionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Restaurant *DetailModal;

@end
```

I konw that I have to modified my viewForAnnotation method but I don't know how to do it. Than you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use this delegate method for right detail button

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    RestMapPin *annView = view.annotation;

    YourViewController *objYourVC= [[YourViewController alloc]init];
    objYourVC.title = annView.title;
    objYourVC.subtitle = annView. subtitle;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objYourVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my low level of objective-c. I have written the method but Xcode said me "Use of undeclared identifier 'annView', 'view' and 'annotation'. Do you know why? `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)viewcalloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    annotation *annView = view.annotation;
    
    RestViewController *objYourVC= [[RestViewController alloc]init];
    objYourVC.TitleLabel = annView.title;
    objYourVC.DescriptionLabel = annView. subtitle;
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objYourVC animated:YES];
}`

Comment: I have updated the question with the RestViewController.h that is the view who should be opened when I press the button in the Map Pin.

Comment: annotation *annView = view.annotation remove this and write this line
RestMapPin *annView =  view.annotation

Comment: where view is the object of MKAnnotationView. please write above method

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster said, use the map view delegate method `mapView:viewCalloutAccessoryControlTapped:`.

I would avise against using the title of the annotation to look up the restaurant though. You should not use display strings to index into your data. That means that if you change a display string, or localize for another language, your lookup no longer works.

I would add an ID field to your annotations and use that.

Comment: I wrote this method but Xcode said me "Use of undeclared identifier 'annView', 'view' and 'annotation'. Do you know why? I have updated the question with the RestViewController.h that is the view who should be opened when I press the button in the Map Pin.

Comment: Edit your code to include the code that is generating errors, along with info about which specific lines generate the error and the complete error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
       RestMapPin *selectedAnnotation = view.annotation;
       NSLog("Title of selected pin - %@", selectedAnnotation.title);
       // Here you get the title of selected annotation
}
```

Now after getting the title of your selected annotation you need to create the object of RestViewController and pass the title in the variable of that controller, Same as you are doing when user select any restaurant from list.

Also, as @Duncan C mentioned in his answer, you should not use String to get the data from server, Strings can be changed.

Comment: It works well but I have a problem: the line `objYourVC.TitleLabel = selectedAnnotation. title;` is working well in the `MapViewController.m` (it shows @"Bacira" for example). But when I go to the other view (called `RestViewController.m`, the `TitleLabel` hasn't got anything (it shows @"Label"). There is any way to solve it. I think that the text is not passing to the other view. Sorry for my code, I want to learn and I will use an integer to get data in next projects). Thank you very much for your help!